# Linebreak after <div>

Tags: css

I want my `<div>` to behave the same way as an `<h1>` tag, so that everything after the `<div>` comes under it, without using the `<br>` tag.

Is there a way to do this only using CSS.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, Which elements need to be breaked under? <p>? <span>?

Comment: `<div>`s by default comes _under_ (means one below one[breaks]) each-other!

Comment: The thing you want is the default behavior, unless you don't specify different style of positioning or make your div floats. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b4hhb/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the `div` should behave the same way as the `h1` except the `h1` has some margin before and after it in most browsers. If you did change some attributes of the `div`, that can result in not working as expected.

To add the margin to your div use CSS like

```
div {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually helped. Sorry for having a unclear question, but I were kinda in a hurry and my english isn't the best.